# Entity Framework DB First add a custom property for all POCO classes generated

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I am using EF 6.1.3 in all my POCO classes I have a common field that takes HTML value. I would like to add a common property for all these POCO classes that will strip HTML and hold clean string.

**Current POCO class**

```
public partial class Category
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Details {get; set;}
}
```

**What I am looking to generate**

```
public partial class Category
{
  public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Details {get; set;}
    public string CleanDetails
    { 
        get{ return StripHtml(this.Details ); } 
    } 
}
```

And I should not lose this custom property every time I update the Entity model

```
public string CleanDetails
    { 
        get{ return StripHtml(this.Details ); } 
    }
```

Tried working on Mode.Context.tt to make the following change, but was not useful

```
 public string EntityClassOpening(EntityType entity)
    {
        return string.Format(
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            "{0} {1}partial class {2}{3}",
            Accessibility.ForType(entity),
            _code.SpaceAfter(_code.AbstractOption(entity)),
            _code.Escape(entity),
            _code.StringBefore(" : ", _typeMapper.GetTypeName(entity.BaseType) ?? "BaseEntity" ));
    }
```

I see there is a way to create partial classes for all those where I need this custom property. But I need this in about 40 classes and there could be more classes coming in future, I want it to be like more of automated approach, then manually creating 40 partial classes.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to [implement inheritance in EF6](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-inheritance-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application). You could create a base class with all your shared methods and properties, then if you made all your entity types inherit from it (see link) you would have the behaviour you are after. The only problem would be that if you deleted a table from your model and then re-added it from the database you would have to make it inherit from base class again.

Answer (score 0):

I generated another folder in my database project for my self and added theses properties in another partial class .add CSharp file to that folder and insert file name same with your class ( Category) and change namespace too

```
public partial class Category
{
    public string CleanDetails
   { 
        get{ return StripHtml(this.Details ); } 
   } 
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I don't want to do. I need this custom property in about 40 POCO classes, and that count may increase. So I wanted to find out if there is a better automated way.